# c# Export Database to HTML formatted table

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am writing a simple application in C# and WPF for reporting. I have following table in a database of sqlite:

```
Table1:
    id
    name
    amntOne
    amntTwo
    entryDate

Table2:
    id
    name
    amntOne
    amntTwo
    location
    entryDate

Table3:
    id
    name
    amntOne
    amntTwo
    location
    entryDate
```

First i want to retrive data from Table1 and Table2. 2nd, i want to accumulate each columns that has same name(For example Table1.amntOne+Table2+amntOne).
3rd, After accumulation insert all columns to the table 3. And finally, I need to create html table to fill with Table3 data.

I don't have any idea where i should start with c#

Comment: Do you know how to write a query to do that in SQL?  The tables are nearly identical.  Is your goal to merge the data in the rows of Table1 and Table2 or to retrieve every row?  I'm not sure what you mean by _accumulate_.

Comment: Table1 and Table2 has few columns with same name(Table1+Table2 become Table3). SO i need to make addition of those same column then insert into Table3. I though it is possible solve the problem with C# instead writing complex SQL query. And i need retrieve every rows.

Comment: id, name, amntOne, amntTwo, location, and entryDate are columns.  The only difference between Table1 and Table2 is the column location.  So you probably mean that the values in name column is probably unique most of the time.  What do you want to do when they match?  Will the row of data where the names are the same have the same id value?  Can you add an example of what the data would look like in Table1 and Table2 and what you want Table3 to look like once it's processed?

Comment: I am sorry, There should be another Table that will have name list with id number. Table1,table2,table3 name column would be nameID which will be used to filter the result. If Table1's amntOne value is 3 and Table2 amntOne value 5 then in table3 amntOne will be 8.

Comment: Does Table1 also have a location column?  Table1, Table2, and Table3 are all the same?  Does anything have to be done with location and entryDate?

Comment: Table1 and Table2's column will exist in Table3. Nothing to do with entryDate. The Table2's location value should be copied to Table3's location .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I have enough to go on now.  Your SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT
  ids.nameId as id,
  t1.name,
  IFNULL(t1.amntOne, 0) + IFNULL(t2.amntOne,0) as amntOne,
  IFNULL(t1.amntTwo, 0) + IFNULL(t2.amntTwo,0) as amntTwo,
  t2.location
FROM
  NameIdTable as ids LEFT JOIN Table1 as t1 ON t1.Id = ids.nameId
                     LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t2.Id = ids.nameId
WHERE
  t1.Id is not null or t2.Id is not null
```

This will return results where there's at least one value in Table1 (t1) or Table2 (t2).  It will add the amounts.  Table2 (t2) is the only table capable of having a location so the value is taken from there.

The results will be your Table3.  You could then use the results to generate your HTML.  Let's say you put your results in a DataTable.  That could look like this:

```
public string GetHtml(DataTable table3)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<table>");
    foreach(var row in table3.Rows) 
    {
        sb.AppendLine("    <tr>");
        sb.AppendLine($"        <td>{row["id"]}</td>");
        sb.AppendLine($"        <td>{row["name"]}</td>");
        sb.AppendLine($"        <td>{row["amntOne"]}</td>");
        sb.AppendLine($"        <td>{row["amntTwo"]}</td>");
        sb.AppendLine($"        <td>{row["location"]}</td>");
        sb.AppendLine("    </tr>");
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</table>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Modify according to your need.  The values for name and location may also need to be escaped for HTML with the above approach.  You may also want to use an `XmlDocument` object to build your HTML. This answer is just to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Perhaps i should filter the query with entryDate column as every month i have insert data(Say, 5-7 rows). I am not expert in c# too. So How the sql query inserting the result to Table3? Also if i add another column called finalAmnt for table1 and table2 and finalAmnt value will be amntOne+amntTwo, what i should do?  I will update soon my progress!